# Using pysnmp for Juniper OIDs (with octets)

Tags: pysnmp

The Juniper [knowledge base](https://kb.juniper.net/InfoCenter/index?page=content&id=KB17526) says that you can hit `jnxOperatingCPU.x.x.x.x` to get the memory usage from the device, and the `x.x.x.x` are "the last 4 octets", in my case "9.1.0.0".

I don't seem to be able to get results like this using pysnmp's getCmd() method.  I have the JUNIPER-MIB in place, but the script returns:

> No symbol JUNIPER-MIB::jnxOperatingCPU.9.1.0.0 at < pysnmp.smi.builder.MibBuilder object at 0x198b810>

I have another SNMP monitoring tool in place that can reach this OID, so I know it's valid on this device.  I can also use the full numeric OID to get the value, but I'd rather have the pretty name.

Might anyone have an example of using such an OID with pysnmp.hlapi?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the error message it looks like you are using the `ObjectIdentity` class incorrectly (pasting code snippet would be helpful though).

According to the [JUNIPER-MIB](http://mibs.snmplabs.com/asn1/JUNIPER-MIB) the `jnxOperatingCPU` object belongs to the `jnxOperatingTable` table which has these indices:

```
jnxOperatingEntry OBJECT-TYPE
    SYNTAX      JnxOperatingEntry
    MAX-ACCESS  not-accessible
    STATUS      current
    DESCRIPTION
        "An entry of operating status table."
    INDEX   { jnxOperatingContentsIndex,
              jnxOperatingL1Index,
              jnxOperatingL2Index,
              jnxOperatingL3Index }
    ::= { jnxOperatingTable 1 }
```

All four indices are of type `Integer32`.

Therefore try this:

```
ObjectIdentity('JUNIPER-MIB', 'jnxOperatingCPU', 9, 1, 0, 0)
```

Here is the [documentation](http://snmplabs.com/pysnmp/docs/api-reference.html#pysnmp.smi.rfc1902.ObjectIdentity) on the `ObjectIdentity` class.

Comment: Sorry about the lack of a code sample - my code base didn't lend me to grab one easily.  You explanation was exactly what I hadn't seen concisely elsewhere, and I'm back on track.